# Haskell - Pattern Synonyms' use in record update

Tags: haskell

I'm now trying out a piece of code from:

https://mpickering.github.io/posts/2015-12-12-pattern-synonyms-8.html

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
pattern MyPoint :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
pattern MyPoint{m, n} = (m,n)
m :: (Int, Int) -> Int
n :: (Int, Int) -> Int
test9 = (0,0) { m = 5 }
```

But `test9` throws an error:

```
• ‘m’ is not a record selector
• In the expression: (0, 0) {m = 5}
```

How do I get `test9` to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write:

```hs
m :: (Int, Int) -> Int
n :: (Int, Int) -> Int
```

You're declaring `m` and `n` as functions and they lose their special place as a record selector. Just drop those lines entirely:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
pattern MyPoint :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
pattern MyPoint{m, n} = (m,n)
test9 = (0,0) { m = 5 } -- (5, 0)
```